# How to convert date structure to char array

Tags: c++

I have a code that outputs date, now i want to convert it to char arrays.

How can i do it properly?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono> 

using namespace std;
using chrono::system_clock;


time_t tt = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now());
struct tm * ptm = localtime(&tt);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `sprintf` function for that task.

```
    char buff[100];
    if(ptm->tm_mon < 10){
            if(ptm->tm_mday < 10){
                    sprintf(buff,"%u-0%u-0%u",(unsigned)ptm->tm_year,(unsigned)ptm->tm_mon,(unsigned)ptm->tm_mday);
            }else{
                    sprintf(buff,"%u-0%u%u",(unsigned)ptm->tm_year,(unsigned)ptm->tm_mon,(unsigned)ptm->tm_mday);
            }
    }else{
            if(ptm->tm_mday < 10){
                    sprintf(buff,"%u-%u-0%u",(unsigned)ptm->tm_year,(unsigned)ptm->tm_mon,(unsigned)ptm->tm_mday);
            }else{
                    sprintf(buff,"%u-%u-%u",(unsigned)ptm->tm_year,(unsigned)ptm->tm_mon,(unsigned)ptm->tm_mday);
            }
    }
```

The rest depends on the desired format.

Comment: thanks, and one more thing, how can i add zero to date, so it will output 07.05.2017, now its output is 5.7.2017